# SQL Server 2008 R2 - RAM = 128GB, PageFile = 192GB?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, pagefile

Is there a definitive guide for PageFile size on the latest 64-bit servers with large amounts of RAM?

I've seen conflicting recommendations, and am wondering if the latest releases have changed the recommendations.

Comment: What you should set the Pagefile to is *highly* dependent on what the server is doing.

Comment: Here's a MS reference  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889654

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running SQL Server on a box with a lot of RAM set the page file to about 6 Gigs.  SQL Server won't swap to disk unless something really wrong happens and allocating 192 gigs of disk space to a page file that will never be used is insane.

Comment: What about the referrals to always setting your page file size to RAM x 1.5 since that's what Windows expects?

Comment: Here's one reference:  http://rusanu.com/2009/11/22/system-pagefile-size-on-machines-with-large-ram/

Comment: On the flip side, the comment on this link: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/buck_woody/archive/2010/06/29/the-windows-page-file-and-sql-server.aspx by Remus Rusanu disputes the 1.5x requirement.

Comment: They are outdated. Old times (little ram) and generic - with SQL Server pecial rules apply as SQL Server basically uses the RAM as cache so it does not hit the disc (slow). Having the cache cached out to disc sort of makes it redundant to start with.